# Calculating the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm stuck with this problem, so I've got the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 4& 6 & 10\\ 
 3& 10 & 13\\ 
 -2&-6  &-8 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which gives me the following identity matrix of $AI$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 4 - \lambda& 6 & 10\\ 
 3& 10 - \lambda & 13\\ 
 -2&-6 & -8 - \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm looking for the Polynomial Characteristic Roots of the Determinant. I can
do this on pen and paper, but I want to make this into an algorithm which can work
on any given `3x3` matrix.

I can then calculate the Determinant of this matrix by doing the following:

$$Det(A) = 4 - \lambda \begin{vmatrix}
 10 - \lambda&13 \\ 
 -6 & -8 - \lambda
\end{vmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
(10 - \lambda \cdot -8 \lambda) - (-6 \cdot 13)
\end{bmatrix}$$

I repeat this process for each of the columns inside the matrix (6, 10)..

Watching this video: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHOsd2PhkqE#t=402)
the guy factorises each of the (A) + (B) + (C) to this equation:

$$ \lambda (\lambda_{2} - 6\lambda+8) = 0$$

And then finds the polynomials: 1, 2, 4.. Which I understand perfectly.

Now, putting this into code and factorising the equation would prove to be difficult. So, I'm asking whether or not there is a simple way to calculate the determinant (using the method given here) and calculate the polynomials without having to factorise the equation.. My aim is to be left with 3 roots based on the Determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a decently efficient way to get the characteristic polynomial of a $3 \times 3$ matrix is to use the [following formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html):
$$
P(x) = -x^3 + [tr(A)]x^2 + [[tr(A)]^2 - tr(A^2)]x +
[[tr(A)]^3 + 2tr(A^3) - 3tr(A)tr(A^2)]
$$
Where $tr(A)$ is the trace of $A$, and $A,A^2,A^3$ are the matrix powers of $A$.

From there, you could use the [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) to get the roots.

---

*there is some computational mistake below*

In this case, we'd compute
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{4&6&10\\3&10&13\\-2&-6&-8} \implies tr(A) = 6\\
A^2 = 
\pmatrix{14&24&38\\16&40&56\\-10&-24&-34} \implies tr(A^2) = 20\\
A^3 = 
\pmatrix{52&96&148\\72&160&232\\-44&-96&-140} \implies tr(A^3) = 72
$$

Comment: I see where you're going with this. Just a tiny bit confusing.. What would the value of $x$ be in the case of the matrix that I gave? Also where you have $tr(A)$ is that the entire matrix, or, the $2x2% based? This sounds like a good solution, but confused over the $x$

Comment: I mean $x$ here the same way you used $\lambda$ in your question.  $A$, $A^2$, and $A^3$ are all matrices without any variables in them.

Comment: Hey, it kind of makes sense. However, if you get some time please can I ask if you could update your answer to give a small example of what: $A,A^2,A^3$ would look like?

Comment: Multiply the matrix $A = \pmatrix{4&6&10\\3&10&13\\-2&-6&-8}$ with itself to get $A^2$.  Multiply by $A$ again to get $A^3$.  Is it not clear what I mean here?

Comment: I see, so I will multiply matrix $A$ by itself to get $A^2$ and then take the $tr$ of that matrix. Okay! One final question before I try this on pen and paper.. Doing this equation will give me the polynomial, but, will it give me just 1 value.. In some instances, I've seen where the polynomial characteristic has been something like $\lambda -4 -5$? Thanks for the help tho :)

Comment: What do you mean by $\lambda - 4 - 5$?  Is that different from $\lambda - 9$?  I mean, in general, polynomials have more than one root, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15084/discussion-between-user1326876-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: I think the equation you gave was not the correct one. Since I am computing the characteristic polynomial, should it therefore not have this form: $f(\lambda) = det(\lambda 1 - A) = \lambda^n - a_{1} * \lambda^n-1 + ....+(-1)^n a_{n}$ Which would intern give the following polynomial (for the matrix I gave in the origin question): $x^3 - 6*x^2 + 8*x$ (Result taken from MATLAB) using: `charpoly(A, x)` where `A` is the 3x3 matrix. What do you think? :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure the equation I gave is a correct one.  However, if you found something else that works, use that.

Comment: I must have made an error when computing the matrix powers, then

Comment: I was not saying it was wrong, I'm just saying that the equation $f(\lambda)$ is the one that MATLAB must implement. There is therefore, no need to use the $A^2 etc..$ but following this equation, what would the values inside the $+....+(-1)$ part be? Would this be adding each of the elements along the $Tr$?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [rule of Sarrus](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) to get the characteristic polynomial and [Cardano's method](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) to get the roots...

Comment: We can use the Rule of Sarrus to get the polynomial? :o

Comment: @user1326876 apply on $A-\lambda I$ to get the determinant, which is the polynominal...